# How to enable End User Languages, when creating a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I work on a multi language application.

While I can find documentation on how to enable the translation workbench in  a scrtach org definition file, how do I 'Enable End User Languages' and setup the 'Available Language List,' that are configured under Company Settings -> Language Settings, in the Setup UI.